# Is it possible to query events from external calendar?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I was able to list events from default google calendar, however when trying to list events from other calendars, I got error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
 }
}
```

I don't know if external calendars aren't supported, or I got the wrong ID of these external cals. I use this method `CalendarList: list` to query for all available calendars from my account, but only the first one works (my default). I'm not sure if this is the right way to get the ID:

```
$calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();

while(true) {
  foreach ($calendarList->getItems() as $calendarListEntry) {
    echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
    echo "\r\n";
  }
  $pageToken = $calendarList->getNextPageToken();
  if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $calendarList = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList($optParams);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I do, the meaning is right below the error code

Comment: The ID of a calendar is the email address from the ID field, not the summary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a test scenario : `CalendarList: get` of a email without properly sharing the calendar to the one authorized to call the function.

[image]

Then, I shared the calendar with the user making the API request:

[image]

Kindly take note that :

[image]

If you are geting the list of events, you should try and use [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list).

Hope this information helps.